# What is the "mnemonicParsing" attribute in Java FX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I have been working with SceneBuilder and I observe that it applies the attribute of `mnemonicParsing` and equates it to `false` for every `Node` that I make.

What exactly is it? What difference does it make in `Layout.xml`?

Comment: Related: [JavaFX Menu - first letter, underline decoration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499500/javafx-menu-first-letter-underline-decoration)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This refers to the [`Labeled.mnemonicParsing` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#mnemonicParsingProperty). It registers a keyboard shortcut to activate the element (using the letter following `_` in the `text` + <kbd>Alt</kbd> (Windows, don't know if it's the same key on other OS too)). E.g.

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("_Say 'Hello World'");
btn.setMnemonicParsing(true);
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
});
```

Will also print `Hello World!`, if the user presses <kbd>Alt</kbd> + S.

This doesn't happen, if `mnemnonicParsing` is `false`. In this case the `_` will also be printed *"normally"* instead of underlineing the following letter.

Comment: hey do you use this yet ?