# How to make Mnemonic work with editable Spinner?

Tags: javafx, spinner, mnemonics

`Mnemonic` mode does **not** change on e. g. <kbd>ALT</kbd> pressed when an ***editable*** `Spinner` is focused. How to fix it? Thank you.

**Minimal, Reproducible Example:**

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EditableSpinnerMnemonicTestApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Spinner<Integer>
                spinner = new Spinner<>(0, 0, 0),
                editableSpinner = new Spinner<>(0, 0, 0);

        spinner.setEditable(false); // (default) Mnemonic mode changes when focused and ALT pressed
        editableSpinner.setEditable(true); // Nothing happens when focused and ALT pressed

        Label label = new Label("_Test");
        label.setMnemonicParsing(true);
        label.setLabelFor(spinner);
        label.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,3,0));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(label, spinner, editableSpinner)));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your OS platform? Is it Windows or Mac? [mnemonics are not supported on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499500/javafx-menu-first-letter-underline-decoration).  Also, what is your JavaFX version?  Potentially there were some [regressions in the mnemonic handling with Java 17](https://www.reddit.com/r/JavaFX/comments/pwfmq2/mnemonic_parsing_in_openjfx_17/).

Comment: Windows with JavaFX 17. Just tested JavaFX 11, 16, 18-ea+4 and it did not work as well. Is it possible to “manually” toggle the mnemonic mode by adding an EventFilter for the editable Spinner or its Editor?

Comment: hmm .. worksforme, provided I set the labelFor to the editableSpinner - is not doing so an oversight in this code example only or also in your project? But then, re-reading your description: all underscores indeed don't change if the editable spinner is focused.

Comment: same for editable combo .. all in win10 with fx17+ and fx11. Looks like the editable spinner/combo swallow the alt for some reason .. you might consider filing an issue :)