# How to assign a shortcut (key combination) to a JavaFx dialog

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have not found a direct way to assign a keyboard shortcut to a button type in a JavaFx 8 dialog.

For instance:

```
dialog.dialogPane().getButtonTypes.addAll(ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.Cancel)
```

How can I assign the ESC key to ButtonType.Cancel ?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't Escape assigned to the cancel button by default?

Comment: Take it just as an example

Comment: In the dialog pane, cant you just add a key listener for whatever keys you want to press the button?

Comment: Yeah you can Hypnic.  But the dialog API is a little weird in that you do things such as getting button instances through the lookupButton API which I found a little unusual until I got used to it.  Hence the longer answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an accelerator as demonstrated in:

- [Using JavaFX 2.2 Mnemonic (and accelerators)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710468/using-javafx-2-2-mnemonic-and-accelerators)

JavaFX dialogs are a bit weird (and complicated) in the way they define and use buttons, so adding the accelerator gets a little convoluted, but is still possible.  The code below sets up an accelerator to fire the button action when a key combination is pressed, shortcut+f, where the shortcut key will change depending on your OS (on OS X it is the key labeled "command").

```
// Create a custom button type:
ButtonType fishingButtonType = new ButtonType( "Go fishing", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OTHER);

dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(fishingButtonType);

// Set an accelerator and an action for the fishing button.
Button fishingButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(fishingButtonType);
fishingButton.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, ae -> {
    // linkware image: http://www.iconka.com
    dialog.setGraphic(new ImageView("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/64/cat-fish-icon.png"));
    ae.consume();  // consume the action so that the dialog does not close when the button is pressed.
});
fishingButton.sceneProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newScene) -> {
    if (newScene != null) {
        newScene.getAccelerators().put(
                new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.F, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN),
                fishingButton::fire
        );
    }
});
```

**Executable Sample Code**

Most of this code is just lifted from the excellent [Makery JavaFX dialog tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/).  Additional code was added to the tutorial code to add the fishing button and the accelerator to trigger it.

Dialog before accelerator triggered:
[image: no fish]

Dialog after accelerator triggered:
[image: go fish]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Pair;

import java.util.Optional;

public class LoginDialog extends Application {

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button showDialogButton = new Button("Show Dialog");
        showDialogButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            showDialog();
        });

        StackPane layout = new StackPane(showDialogButton);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));

        stage.show();
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        // Create the custom dialog.
        Dialog<Pair<String, String>> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Login Dialog");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Look, a Custom Login Dialog");

        // Set the icon.
        // icon source: http://www.iconarchive.com/show/soft-scraps-icons-by-hopstarter/Lock-Lock-icon.html
        dialog.setGraphic(new ImageView("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/soft-scraps/64/Lock-Lock-icon.png"));

        // Set the button types.
        ButtonType loginButtonType = new ButtonType("Login", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
        ButtonType fishingButtonType = new ButtonType( "Go fishing", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OTHER);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(loginButtonType, fishingButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);

        // Create the username and password labels and fields.
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

        TextField username = new TextField();
        username.setPromptText("Username");
        PasswordField password = new PasswordField();
        password.setPromptText("Password");

        grid.add(new Label("Username:"), 0, 0);
        grid.add(username, 1, 0);
        grid.add(new Label("Password:"), 0, 1);
        grid.add(password, 1, 1);

        // Enable/Disable login button depending on whether a username was entered.
        Node loginButton = dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(loginButtonType);
        loginButton.setDisable(true);

        // Set an accelerator and an action for the fishing button.
        Button fishingButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(fishingButtonType);
        fishingButton.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, ae -> {
            // linkware image: http://www.iconka.com
            dialog.setGraphic(new ImageView("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/64/cat-fish-icon.png"));
            ae.consume();
        });
        fishingButton.sceneProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newScene) -> {
            if (newScene != null) {
                newScene.getAccelerators().put(
                        new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.F, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN),
                        fishingButton::fire
                );
            }
        });

        // Do some validation (using the Java 8 lambda syntax).
        username.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            loginButton.setDisable(newValue.trim().isEmpty());
        });

        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

        // Request focus on the username field by default.
        Platform.runLater(username::requestFocus);

        // Convert the result to a username-password-pair when the login button is clicked.
        dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
            if (dialogButton == loginButtonType) {
                return new Pair<>(username.getText(), password.getText());
            }
            return null;
        });

        Optional<Pair<String, String>> result = dialog.showAndWait();

        result.ifPresent(usernamePassword -> {
            System.out.println("Username=" + usernamePassword.getKey() + ", Password=" + usernamePassword.getValue());
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```