# Mneumonic Parsing not working on Mac?

Tags: java, javafx

I've just started learning JavaFX, and tried out the `setMneumonicParsing()` method. However, I have a Mac, and it's not working. 
I understand that on Windows you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the letter after the <kbd>_</kbd>. I've tried pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and many combinations of these but nothing seems to work. 
Anyone have any experience with this?

Here's an excerpt from the code:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        // Create a Button or any control item
        Button myButton = new Button();
        myButton.setMnemonicParsing(true);
        myButton.setText("_Count");
```

Comment: Either mnemonic or pneumatic - pick your poison. Mneumonic is neither a word nor or a method in JavaFX Button ;) However MnemonicParsing is enabled by default. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a know issue with Mac. Try to utilize accelerators. Also check here:
 [Using JavaFX 2.2 Mnemonic (and accelerators)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710468/using-javafx-2-2-mnemonic-and-accelerators)